# how to give the alert message when the particular field is not entered>

Tags: html

I wrote html program such that when i not entered the field i want alert message ..i have tried with oninvalid function.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>DIABETES RISK SCORE SYSTEM</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="lightgreen" text="black" style="font-size:18pt;font-family:Garamond"><center>
    <h2>DIABETES RISK SCORE SYSTEM</h2></center>

    <form name=form1 >
    <table name=tab cellspacing=30pt>
        <tr>
            <td align=left>
                <h2>Enter your Name :</h2>
                </td><td align=right><input type=text name=t1 size=18><br/><br/>
                <a href="taketest.php" class="btn">BACK</a>
                <a href="Gender.php" class="btn">NEXT</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53372082/edit), then click the snippet editor `[<>]` and create a [mcve] - You did not post any script

Comment: Stackoverflow expects you to perform [a degree of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/19068) **before** you ask a question (and to share the results of that research in the question). There is nothing here which suggests you've investigated form validation at all.

Comment: CSS is over two decades old. Do not use tables for layout (or presentational attributes, or `<centre>`, etc.)

Comment: or form name ;) - and there is no such thing as a named table

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/) . `<h2>` elements are not labels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `required` attribute. When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form. In your code, you could have something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="t1" size=18 required>
```

the required attribute works with the following input types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, date pickers, number, checkbox, radio, and file. You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_required.asp) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation).

Cheers!

Comment: @RamyashreeBhat you can mark my answer as accepted (or upvote it) if it helped you :) Cheers!